# Jquery datepicker disappers on postback

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using jquery datepicker and after postback, the date seems to disapper.
I had tried using datepicker text(input) in updatepanel but did not work

```
 $(function () {
    $("#datepicker_From").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
    $("#datepicker_To").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
});


In UI:
    From Date:
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker_From" name="txt_Fdatepicker" value="">
    </p>
    To Date:
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker_To" name="txt_Tdatepicker" value="">
    </p>
```

Code Behind :

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["FromDate"] =null;
                Session["ToDate"] = null;                
                BindGrid();
            }
            string fromDate = Request.Form["txt_Fdatepicker"];
            string todate = Request.Form["txt_Tdatepicker"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fromDate) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(todate))
            {
                DateTime app_FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
                DateTime app_ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(todate);
                Session["FromDate"] = app_FromDate;
                Session["ToDate"] = app_ToDate;
}
```

//Assigning the value in session, since it disappers after postback

Comment: Can you show more code? Your postback code for example. Sounds like you are using ASP.NET AJAX (?) I think there is a property on ScriptManager / updatepanel to keep values after the postback. Otherwise it will just show the original value of the controls (ie: blank).

Comment: Of course, the simplest option is to write the new value into the field in the server postback handler.

Comment: I am 100% sure you are using `UpdatePanel`